# JS и TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, lodash

Использую шаблонизатор [**lodash**](https://lodash.com/) в своей работе. При подгрузке файла Ajax, содержимое подгружается и код отрабатывается, но консоль выдает ошибку:

> Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Подскажите, как можно найти причину данной ошибки?

Comment: Для начала, представить нам код.

Comment: Похожая проблема https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/689956

Comment: Вы полагаете массивом или строкой, то, что не является ни массивом, ни строкой